how to disable interpolation in plotly?
I have something like following:
    fig.add_layout_image(
        dict(
            source=prefix_webp + base64.b64encode(webp_data).decode("utf-8"),
            xref='x', yref='y',  # Reference subplot axes
            x=0, y= 1,  # Position in subplot grid
            sizex=1, sizey=1,
            xanchor='left', yanchor='top',
            sizing='contain',  # Ensure it fits within the given size
        ),
        row=row, col=col
    )

Sine the image has small amount of pixels. If I save the figure as PDF, the image is pixelated which is what I wanted, because it is actually represent some data, I would like to see the exact edge of each pixel.
However, if I display it in browser or save it as html. The image seems interpolated and becomes smooth.
I wonder how can I disable this in plotly
try to add the css via template does not really work
html_template = '''
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Plotly Layout Image Example</title>
    <style>
        /* Custom CSS to apply pixelated rendering to images */
        img {
            image-rendering: pixelated;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>Plotly Layout Image Example</h1>
    <!-- This is where the Plotly figure will be inserted -->
    {{ fig | safe }}

</body>
</html>
'''

plotly_html = fig.to_html(full_html=False)

from jinja2 import Template
template = Template(html_template)
html_output = template.render(fig=plotly_html)
with open(os.path.expanduser('test-css.html'), 'w') as file:
    file.write(html_output)


The simplest would be to use a heatmap instead of a layout image. Otherwise you could apply the css rule image-rendering: pixelated; to the image element in your html.

can you show us how can I inject the css rule in the layout image? I do not know can I use heatmap or imshow with existing webp_data without decode it. If you show me how to do that it could also be an answer

finally it works. We need to identify the image tag as svg image.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Plotly Layout Image Example</title>
    <style>
        /* Custom CSS to apply pixelated rendering to images */
        svg image {
            image-rendering: pixelated;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>Plotly Layout Image Example</h1>
    <!-- This is where the Plotly figure will be inserted -->
    {{ fig | safe }}

</body>
</html>

This template finally works
